# Assigning Date from SQL Server to Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angular-date-format

This always seems to be a nightmare for me. am new to angular js. Please suggest me the best solution.
I have datefield from MS SQL Server, which to be displayed in HTML Page in input date type field. But am not getting the date assigned. In SQL Server it is a DATETIME field

Html Code

```
<input type="date" id="end_date" ng-model="end_date" value="{{end_date}}" />
```

JS Code

```
$scope.end_date = response.data[0].end_date;
```

I even tried with

```
response.data[0].end_date.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can debug your code with console.log() to see if the data is set correct.
Also the the value for the type "date" need to have this format "YYYY-MM-DD". It won't work with a datetime string.